# Boost.Graph: saving and loading a boost::adjacency_list with a name

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

Of a boost::adjaceny_list I am able to get and set the graph its name. Sadly, I cannot get it to be saved and loaded to/from file. I can get the saving and loading of vertices and edges to work, but the graph property works differently.

In the full tested-to-compile code below, I show:

- How to create an empty directed graph with a name
- Set and get the graph its name
- Load and save the graph
- main: set a graph its name, save, load, check if the result still has that name

First the groundwork:

- How to create an empty directed graph with a name
- Set and get the graph its name

These functions are close to trivially short:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <string>

boost::adjacency_list<
  boost::vecS,
  boost::vecS,
  boost::directedS,
  boost::no_property,
  boost::no_property,
  boost::property<boost::graph_name_t,std::string>
>
create_empty_directed_graph_with_graph_name() noexcept
{
  return {};
}

template <typename graph>
void set_graph_name(const std::string& name, graph& g) noexcept
{
  get_property(g, boost::graph_name) = name;
}

template <typename graph>
std::string get_graph_name(const graph& g) noexcept
{
  return get_property(g, boost::graph_name
  );
}
```

The test I want to get to work:

```
int main()
{
  const std::string dot_filename{"test.dot"};
  auto g = create_empty_directed_graph_with_graph_name();
  set_graph_name("TestGraph", g);
  save_graph_with_graph_name_to_dot(g, dot_filename);
  const auto h = load_directed_graph_with_graph_name_from_dot(dot_filename);
  assert(get_graph_name(g) == get_graph_name(h));
}
```

Steps are: (1) set a graph its name (2) save it (3) load a graph (4) check if it has the same name

The code I have I question about is the saving. I save the graph with a name like this:

```
template <typename graph>
void save_graph_with_graph_name_to_dot(
  const graph& g, const std::string& filename
)
{
  std::ofstream f(filename);
  boost::write_graphviz(
    f,
    g,
    boost::default_writer(),
    boost::default_writer(),
    [g](std::ostream& os) {
      os << "name=\""
        << get_graph_name(g)
        << "\";\n";
    }
  );
}
```

I am unsure if this is the way to go. It produces the following .dot file:

```
digraph G {
name="TestGraph";
}
```

I wonder if it shouldn't have said 'digraph TestGraph' instead, but it is accepted as a valid .dot file.

Loading this file is where I am stuck at. I do not even how to get it to compile. I do know how to (save and) load any type of edge and vertex (see [a Boost.Graph tutorial](https://github.com/richelbilderbeek/BoostGraphTutorial)), but here I am lost. Here is my attempt:

```
boost::adjacency_list<
  boost::vecS,
  boost::vecS,
  boost::directedS,
  boost::no_property,
  boost::no_property,
  boost::property<boost::graph_name_t, std::string>
>
load_directed_graph_with_graph_name_from_dot(
  const std::string& dot_filename
)
{
  std::ifstream f(dot_filename.c_str());
  auto g = create_empty_directed_graph_with_graph_name();

  //#define TODO_KNOW_HOW_TO_LOAD_A_GRAPH_ITS_NAME
  #ifdef TODO_KNOW_HOW_TO_LOAD_A_GRAPH_ITS_NAME
  boost::dynamic_properties p;
  p.property("name",get_property(g,boost::graph_name)); //Something like this?
  #else
  boost::dynamic_properties p(
    boost::ignore_other_properties
  );
  #endif
  boost::read_graphviz(f,g,p);
  return g;
}
```

I hope someone knows how to save and load a graph with a name. It shouldn't be too hard, should it?

Here is the full complete listing:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/properties.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

boost::adjacency_list<
  boost::vecS,
  boost::vecS,
  boost::directedS,
  boost::no_property,
  boost::no_property,
  boost::property<boost::graph_name_t,std::string>
>
create_empty_directed_graph_with_graph_name() noexcept
{
  return {};
}

template <typename graph>
void set_graph_name(const std::string& name, graph& g) noexcept
{
  get_property(g, boost::graph_name) = name;
}

template <typename graph>
std::string get_graph_name(const graph& g) noexcept
{
  return get_property(g, boost::graph_name
  );
}

template <typename graph>
void save_graph_with_graph_name_to_dot(
  const graph& g, const std::string& filename
)
{
  std::ofstream f(filename);
  boost::write_graphviz(
    f,
    g,
    boost::default_writer(),
    boost::default_writer(),
    //Unsure if this results in a graph that can be loaded correctly from a .dot file
    [g](std::ostream& os) {
      os << "name=\""
        << get_graph_name(g)
        << "\";\n";
    }
  );
}

boost::adjacency_list<
  boost::vecS,
  boost::vecS,
  boost::directedS,
  boost::no_property,
  boost::no_property,
  boost::property<boost::graph_name_t, std::string>
>
load_directed_graph_with_graph_name_from_dot(
  const std::string& dot_filename
)
{
  std::ifstream f(dot_filename.c_str());
  auto g = create_empty_directed_graph_with_graph_name();

  //#define TODO_KNOW_HOW_TO_LOAD_A_GRAPH_ITS_NAME
  #ifdef TODO_KNOW_HOW_TO_LOAD_A_GRAPH_ITS_NAME
  boost::dynamic_properties p;
  p.property("name",get_property(g,boost::graph_name)); //Something like this?
  #else
  boost::dynamic_properties p(
    boost::ignore_other_properties
  );
  #endif
  boost::read_graphviz(f,g,p);
  return g;
}

int main()
{
  const std::string dot_filename{"test.dot"};
  auto g = create_empty_directed_graph_with_graph_name();
  set_graph_name("TestGraph", g);
  save_graph_with_graph_name_to_dot(g, dot_filename);
  const auto h = load_directed_graph_with_graph_name_from_dot(dot_filename);
  assert(get_graph_name(g) == get_graph_name(h));
}
```

Comment: You can find an example in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/read_graphviz.html#example). (Totally unintuitive). [With your code (more or less)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02cae738e34a1001).

Answer (score 0):

cv_and_he: thanks! I did see that page, but had a hard time reading it!

Answer: the loading part of the code needs to be changed to this:

```
boost::adjacency_list<
  boost::vecS,
  boost::vecS,
  boost::directedS,
  boost::no_property,
  boost::no_property,
  boost::property<boost::graph_name_t, std::string>
>
load_directed_graph_with_graph_name_from_dot(
  const std::string& dot_filename
)
{
  using graph = boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS,
    boost::vecS,
    boost::directedS,
    boost::no_property,
    boost::no_property,
    boost::property<boost::graph_name_t, std::string>
  >;


  std::ifstream f(dot_filename.c_str());
  auto g = create_empty_directed_graph_with_graph_name();

  boost::ref_property_map<graph*,std::string>
    graph_name(get_property(g,boost::graph_name)
  );

  boost::dynamic_properties dp;
  dp.property("name",graph_name);

  boost::read_graphviz(f,g,dp);
  return g;
}
```

Comment: General hint: you can probably just [search (my) answers on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+read_graphviz)